# How to set an input element as disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

```
<input type="radio" @(Model.IsradACHDisabled ? "disabled" : "") asp-for="SelectedPaymentType" id="radACH" value="ACH" />ACH<br />
```

For the above code the disable attribute works but the SelectedPaymentType value is lost on a POST

```
<input type="radio" asp-for="SelectedPaymentType" id="radACH" value="ACH" />ACH<br />
```

With the above code SelectedPaymentType I can get back on a POST but how do I set the disabled attribute

Comment: Disabled input does not get posted, try using the `readonly` instead (you can style it so it looks disabled).

Answer (score 2):

It just performed as excepted,if you set the inputbox disabled,when you submit the form,the value won't be submitted,
You could try with readonly attribute instead,also,you could modify the property when you submit the form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Post">
    <input  name="PostId">
    
    <input id="someinput" disabled="disabled" name="Description" value="des">
    <div class="blog-item position-relative overflow-hidden rounded mb-2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#form').submit(function() {
        $("#someinput").prop('disabled', false);
    
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I basically want to set the "disabled" property based on a value in the Model

Answer (score 2):

You may use a Hidden Input to hold that value for post back purpose while remain the existing Input as disabled.

If your POST if for database update, it is recommend do not use the SelectedPaymentType value from POST. This can lead to security hole, other can still manipulate this value.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I discovered the below code will work and it also handles postback

```
<input type="radio" disabled=@(Model.IsradUSPSDisabled ? "disabled" : null) asp-for="SelectedMailingType" id="radUSPS" value="USPS" />USPS
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use :

```
<input type="radio" @Model.IsradACHDisabled ? "disabled" : "" asp-for="SelectedPaymentType" id="radACH" value="ACH" />ACH1<br />
```

or:

```
@if(Model.IsradACHDisabled=="disabled")
{
 <input type="radio" disabled asp-for="SelectedPaymentType" id="radACH" value="ACH" />ACH1<br />
}
else{
   <input type="radio"  asp-for="SelectedPaymentType" id="radACH" value="ACH" />ACH1<br />
}
```

Comment: "*For the above code the disable attribute works but the SelectedPaymentType value is lost on a POST*"

Comment: <input type="radio" @Model.IsradACHDisabled ? "disabled" : "" asp-for="SelectedPaymentType" id="radACH" value="ACH" />ACH1<br />

Does not work, VS is stating that "Missing Attribute Name"

Comment: I test with the code,and it will get `<input type="radio" disabled name="SelectedPaymentType" id="radACH" value="ACH" />ACH<br />`

Comment: I know the above code works but the following code which uses the model to set the readonly flag does not work, in fact in Visual Studio the tags "asp-for" and "type" doesn't change color like it normally does


<input type="radio" @(Model.IsradACHDisabled ? "readonly" : "") asp-for="SelectedPaymentType" id="radACH" value="ACH" />ACH<br />